# Testing in IE6 on a Mac

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6, parallels, iepngfix

As of now, I don't have a PC to test IE6 on.  I have parallels and have tried all the side-by-side apps, virtual machines, etc, but I'm still not sure if they process

1. javascript correctly, and
2. Microsoft Conditional Comments.

I have some PNG 24s in my site, and I'm using the DD_belatedPNG script to make them work.  However, I can't tell if its working or not!  It appears not to be, however, I'm still not certain whether the VMs and side-by-side are working with the Javascript correctly.

Any thoughts?

Comment: http://browsershots.org/ - thats a got all of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a virtual machine to run Windows XP, everything should work pretty much as it would on a PC.  A virtual environment emulates another hardware system.  In VMWare, for instance, you'll find that the virtual machine has it's own BIOS and specifications that are likely to be different than your Mac.  The virtual machine should behave as if it knows nothing of your Mac.

The operating system you install on a Mac, Windows XP for example, should be the same Windows XP that another user would have on a PC.

Comment: ah i see, well then i suppose I'm doing something wrong with my PNG fix here.  But I'll leave that for another post.  thanks!

Comment: @dtj: the one exception here is if youre uing the multiple IE hacks that are out there. they dont always work as expected. The only sure fire thing to do is have a different VM for each version of IE you need to test in.

Comment: Yes, don't trust multiple IE hacks. The CSS behaves differently. IE can also behave differently running on WinXP compared to Vista or Windows7. The best is to have one VM for each combination of IE+windows. Note that I've also experienced different behaviors for IE7 on WinXP depending on weather or not service pack 3 is installed.

Comment: ... (continued) This means that even on Windows, the best is still to test your site on multiple VMs.